# ASP.NEt Detect and Show Session Expired Message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got my MVC ASP.NET web.config setup like one below:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="1" />
</authentication>
```

When session expired, it automatically goes to LogOn Page. This may confused the end users. Would be good to show the message "Session Expired,please relogin".

Could anyone please guide me through how to achieve above? The message can be single page or even within Login Page itself.

Thanks Heaps.

Answer (score 2):

global.asax

```
protected void Session_Start(object src, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Session != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession)
    {
        string sCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
        if (null != sCookieHeader && sCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)
            Response.Redirect("/Session/Timeout");
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="/*duration*/"/>
```

Comment: Thanks david, should that be Session_End instead?

Comment: i dont think you can redirect from Session_End